# TS check if Type contains 'null' Type

Tags: typescript, type-systems

I have the following both Typescript Types defined. One of the type contains `null`the other neither. Is it possible to check such type for the existence of `null`?

```
type TransactionCategory = "B2B"| "SEZWP" | "SEZWOP" | "EXPWP" | "EXPWOP" | "DEXP" | null

type DutyStatus = "WPOD" | "WOPOD"
```

I don't want to check such stuff on the concrete instance but on the type system itself. Similar to the `in` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *exactly* clear what you're asking, but...

If you just want to get a boolean verdict from the compiler about whether the type `null` is included in a union type, then you can write a simple [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to check that:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcEGNgEsD2SDCCwEA5jnCFALxQBEAQgEz20A+dAygKIBaA6gAVaUdrW78A8kJF0uADQGDho+YqnK6AEVUakAVwA2BgNwAoUJCia9oDsCJ6U1OoImaNtPlLe0z58NAAkkjoBnoAJhAoAHKGBgA8MAB8zvpGUBAAHsRI4U4wUAD8UMBwetAAXFAAZggGKBB+FtDwyGiYuAREpOQgwaERUbHpNP1hkTFxiYioGNh4hMRkFElmUOsA9BsAeoWm-pbWtvbAjmODkyNQ5xPDCUcgdg4oq6brUFu7pkA)

```ts
type TransactionCategory = "B2B"| "SEZWP" | "SEZWOP" | "EXPWP" | "EXPWOP" | "DEXP" | null;
type DutyStatus = "WPOD" | "WOPOD";

type IncludesNull<T> = null extends T ? true : false;

type TransactionCategoryIncludesNull = IncludesNull<TransactionCategory>;
   //^? type TransactionCategoryIncludesNull = true

type DutyStatusIncludesNull = IncludesNull<DutyStatus>;
   //^? type DutyStatusIncludesNull = false
```